# To find orthogonal complement of a subset in inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a inner product space and $S$ be a subset of $V$, then how do I show the intersection of S with its orthogonal complement in V is $\{0\}$.
    If I take $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $S=\{1,2\}$, then the orthogonal complement of $S$ is $\{0\}$ 
and so, the intersection between them is empty, so how do I show the intersection of $S$ with its orthogonal complement in $V$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: You're correct that the answer might be the empty set in general. If you assume that $S$ is a subspace, which is perhaps the most natural situation, then the answer is always $\{0\}$. (Indeed, regardless of the structure of $S$, the answer is dependably $\{0\}$ or $\emptyset$ depending on whether $0\in S$; one simply proves that if $v$ is in both $S$ and its orthogonal complement then $v=0$.)

Answer (score 1):

Every element $v$ in a subspace $S$ can be represented by its basic vectors $s_1,\ldots,s_N$ as

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i s_i$$

Equivalently, if $v$ lies in $S^{\perp}$, then

$$v=\sum_{j=1}^N b_j s^{\perp}_j$$

holds. Thus, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i s_i=\sum_{j=1}^N b_j s^{\perp}_j$$

In other words, each $s_i$ can be generated by the sum of $s^{\perp}_i$. More precisely,

$$s_i=\sum_{j=1}^N \langle s_i, s^{\perp}_j\rangle s^{\perp}_j$$

But because $S^\perp$ is orthogonal to $S$, the inner product is zero, thus to have the equality, all $a_i$ and $b_i$ are zero.

Combining all steps, this means
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^N 0 \cdot s_i = 0$$
thus the intersection is only the $0$ vector.

Comment: It's ok, but I am talking about the subset here,not subspace

Comment: can you tell the same thing always for a subset S of V?

Comment: The orthogonal complement of any subset $S$ is always a subspace and is equal to the orthogonal complement of the subspace that is spanned by all vectors in $S$. Thus, by proving it for the spanned set, we have directly shown it for all subspaces too.

Comment: For suppose,S is the subset with with some non zero elements in inner product space $\mathbb{R}$ , then orhogonal complement of S is the null space, then how do I say that their intersection is {0}.

Comment: If you have a non zero element subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then the orthogonal complement is not null! Its the subspace containing only the element $\{0\}$. But of course if your set $S$ does not contain the element $0$, the intersection will not have it either, so your theorem is wrong.